# PHP SQL LEFT JOIN Statement lost one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I'm using the query suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816820/6822845 to list my table contents. This is working really fine, I get a list of every section with its subsections comma seperated in another column so I can explode it and convert it to an array. My problem is, that my sections table(mentioned under my other post linked above) has another column named "sorder" that holds the displaying order. I don't know why, but I'm not able to output it with the column selects as its every time 0.

```
SELECT sections.sorder as sorder ,section_titel as t1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(sub_section_titel) as t2 
FROM sections
    LEFT JOIN sub_sections ON section_id = sId
GROUP BY t1
ORDER by sorder
```

Every time I run it sorder displays as "0". But it's not 0. The weird thing is, that I can read the "iorder" column which is in my sub_section table. But the "sorder"-column which is in the main-table "sections" isn't accessible / every time 0.  I'm using Mysql:

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: `SELECT sections.sorder as sorder section_titel as t1,` you're lacking a comma after sorder

Comment: Oh i lost the comme while editing this text. But its in my code and there is to syntax error in it. Just the logic doesnt work. And i'm using mySQL

Comment: Can you show sample data including sorder?

Comment: can you show a sqlfiddler example?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you used `GROUP BY` with `section_id` instead of `section_titel`?

Comment: Is there an `sorder` field in table `sub_sections`? Can't replicate this issue and you have not provided some more data. This is better `SELECT s.sorder as sorder , s.section_titel as t1, GROUP_CONCAT(sbs.sub_section_titel) as t2 FROM sections s LEFT JOIN sub_sections sbs ON s.section_id = sbs.sId GROUP BY s.section_id ORDER by s.sorder`

Answer (score 0):

I've created an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46275f/3) which I hope represents your data. In that example, `ORDER BY sorder` works fine. I've also included an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` so that subsection titles can be ordered to. So, with the original query:

```
SELECT section_titel as t1, GROUP_CONCAT(sub_section_titel) as t2 
FROM sections LEFT JOIN sub_sections ON section_id = sId
GROUP BY t1
```

The output is

```
t1              t2
Section One     SubOne,SubTwo
Section Three   SubThree
Section Two     (null)
```

But with the new query:

```
SELECT sorder, section_titel as t1, GROUP_CONCAT(sub_section_titel ORDER BY iorder) as t2 
FROM sections LEFT JOIN sub_sections ON section_id = sId
GROUP BY t1
ORDER BY sorder
```

The output is:

```
sorder  t1              t2
1       Section Three   SubThree
2       Section One     SubTwo,SubOne
3       Section Two     (null)
```

Note reordering of `Section Three` and `Section One` and also `SubTwo` and `SubOne` based on the values of `sorder` and `iorder`.

Comment: Did this help? If not, can you provide some more information (e.g. actual table structure since I have just guessed at it) to help solve the problem?